# Why i receive close() was never explicitly called on database

Tags: android, sqlite

Why i receive this error?

```
close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.quickorder/databases/QuickOrderDB'
```

this is my code in DatabaseHandler:

```
    void addCliente(Anpcfbcf cliente) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(BCCSC, cliente.getBCCSC()); 
    values.put(BCACC, cliente.getBCACC()); 
    values.put(BCAIN, cliente.getBCAIN());
    values.put(BCCAP, cliente.getBCCAP()); 
    values.put(BCALO, cliente.getBCALO()); 
    values.put(BCCPR, cliente.getBCCPR()); 
    values.put(BCCTE, cliente.getBCCTE()); 
    values.put(BCCPA, cliente.getBCCPA()); 

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(ANPCFBCF, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is the only possible place you do something from the database?

Comment: Usually this happens if there is another open connection that is not closed. You have to close all open connections, not just one.

Comment: Answers galore right over there ->

Answer (score 1):

This is [answered repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=close%28%29%20was%20never%20explicitly%20called%20on%20database), even in the related sidebar column.